# R dataframe: Finding index of duplicated values with maximum score

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Let's say I have a dataframe like:

```
x = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
y = c(1, 5, 4, 2, 3)
d = data.frame(x, y)
```

I need to remove duplicates in x, by taking the x with the highest y. I need to get a TRUE/FALSE vector corresponding to the rows to kept, like:

```
v = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(d["y"],d["x"],max)`

Comment: @nicola: Elegant answer. 'aggregate' generally needs (formula,data,fn) or (data,by,fn) arguments. How does this (column1,column2,fn) working?

Comment: The single square bracket is the key. `aggregate` needs lists (or dataframes) as the first two arguments. `d["y"]` is a dataframe (and so a list) with one column, as opposed to `d[["y"]]` which is just an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a logical index

```
 as.logical(with(d, ave(y, x, FUN=function(.y) .y==max(.y))))
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or

```
 with(d, ave(y,x, FUN=max)==y)
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or using `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(d)[,list(y==max(y)), by=x]$V1
  #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you just want to remove the rows:

```
  d[with(d, ave(y,x, FUN=max)==y),]
```

Or for `data.table`

```
  setDT(d)[, list(y=max(y)), by=x]
```